# Ordenar columna de mayor a menor en dataGridView

Tags: c#

Tengo este método que consume un api

```
private void OrdenesTrabajoAPI()
{
    try
    {
        string Desde = DateTime.Now.Date.ToString("o", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        string Hasta = DtHasta.Value.ToString("o", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        var client = new RestClient("https://fleet.cloudfleet.com/api/v1/work-orders/?createdAtFrom=" + Desde + "&createdAtTo=" + Hasta + "");
        client.Timeout = -1;
        var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
        request.AddHeader("Authorization", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["KEY"]);
        request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
        request.AddParameter("application/json; charset=utf-8", "", ParameterType.RequestBody);
        IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
        if (response.Content.Contains("No Work Orders found with the specified filters"))
        {
            lblError.Text = "No se encontraron órdenes de trabajo con las fechas especificados";
        }
        else
        {
            List<Vehiculos> ob = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Vehiculos>>(response.Content);
            dataGridView2.DataSource = ob;
        }
        MessageBox.Show(response.Content);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Como ven los datos que trae del api los mete en el

```
dataGridView2.DataSource = ob;
```

y los carga de este manera

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Necesito ordenar la columna **number** de mayor a menor

con este código supuestamente los ordena

```
dataGridView2.Sort(dataGridView2.Columns[0], System.ComponentModel.ListSortDirection.Ascending);
```

Pero me sale lo siguiente

'Para que se pueda ordenar, un control DataGridView debe estar enlazado a un objeto IBindingList.'

**JSON**

```
 [
  {
    "number": 2657,
    "vehicleCode": "C9M955",
    "workshopDate": "2020-09-30T14:35:00.0000000Z",
    "startDate": "2020-09-30T14:35:00.0000000Z",
    "estimatedFinishDate": "2020-09-30T15:35:00.0000000Z",
    "status": "opened",
    "odometer": 210500,
    "hourmeter": null,
    "vendor": {
      "id": 72791,
      "name": "Almacen y taller Autocar inyeccion"
    },
    "reason": null,
    "detectedIssue": null,
    "paymentCondition": null,
    "warranty": null,
    "comments": null,
    "driver": null,
    "maintenanceLabels": null,
    "type": null,
    "city": null,
    "costCenter": null,
    "primaryGroup": null,
    "secundaryGroup": null,
    "createdAt": "2021-01-18T14:37:03.2170000Z",
    "createdBy": {
      "id": 19718,
      "name": "Juan Perez"
    },
    "affectsMaintenanceSchedule": true,
    "affectsVehicleAvailability": true,
    "updatedAt": "2021-01-18T14:42:30.1500000Z",
    "updatedBy": {
      "id": 19718,
      "name": "Juan Perez"
    },
    "totalCostLabors": 24500,
    "totalCostParts": 0,
    "totalCost": 24500,
    "technicalCompletionDate": null,
    "finalCompletionDate": null,
    "lastSystemTechnicalCompletionDate": null,
    "lastSystemFinalCompletionDate": null
  }
]
```

Solución

```
  private void OrdenesTrabajoAPI()
        {
            try
            {
                string Desde = DateTime.Now.Date.ToString("o", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                string Hasta = DtHasta.Value.ToString("o", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                var client = new RestClient("https://fleet.cloudfleet.com/api/v1/work-orders/?createdAtFrom=" + Desde + "&createdAtTo=" + Hasta + "");
                client.Timeout = -1;
                var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
                request.AddHeader("Authorization", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["KEY"]);
                request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
                request.AddParameter("application/json; charset=utf-8", "", ParameterType.RequestBody);
                IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
                if (response.Content.Contains("No Work Orders found with the specified filters"))
                {
                    lblError.Text = "No se encontraron órdenes de trabajo con las fechas especificados";
                }
                else
                {
                    List<Vehiculos> ob = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Vehiculos>>(response.Content);
                    dataGridView2.DataSource = ob;
                    dataGridView2.DataSource = (from o in ob
                           orderby  o.number descending
                           select o).ToList();
                }
                MessageBox.Show(response.Content);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Ordena la lista antes de asignarla al datagridview

Comment: Pues si pero como me genera lo siguiente,'Para que se pueda ordenar, un control DataGridView debe estar enlazado a un objeto IBindingList.'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Variante 1:**

Como tienes el **objeto ob** el cual ya existe podrías hacer:

```
datagridview.DataSource = (from o in ob
                           order by o.Numero descending
                           select o).ToList();
```

Guardas en el **DataGridView** la lista de vehículos, ordenada por el número descendentemente. La **variable ob**, debe ser una **variable global** para que sirva en cualquier lugar.

**Variante2:**

Específicamente tu error te da porque no tienes tu **DataGridView** enlazado a un **BindingSource**, para ello debes crear un **objeto DataSource**:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Después sale esta otra ventana, donde escogerías el origen del dato, si es de una base de datos, o un objeto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando creas el **DataSource**, puedes arrastrar hacia el formulario el campo o los campos que desees(**ver imagen 1**) o todos los campos, en el ejemplo que te pongo arrastrarías el **campo Autor** y esto ya te crea un **DataGridView** con todos los campos que desees, te genera además el **objeto BindingSource**, que es el que sirve de enlace entre nuestros datos y los componentes visuales, y cada campo que arrastres tendría su **propiedad DataSource** enlazada al **BindingSource** creado.

Entonces podrías poner:

```
bindingSource.DataSource = (from o in ob
                            order by o.Numero descending
                            select o).ToList();
```

y como el **DataGridView** está enlazado a este **BindingSource** a través de su **propiedad DataSource** pues los cambios se van a reflejar en él.

Fíjate que en la **variante1** usas el **objeto DataGridView** y en esta el **objeto BindingSource.**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Gracias, puse la solución en la pregunta, use linq.